# FabricJS - Change Rotation Icon Line Height?

Tags: jquery, canvas, fabricjs

I'd like to change the line height of the rotation icon, an example given on this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRKu6.jpg

I'm unsure on how to do this, I've checked drawControls and the customisation section on the fabricJS website to no avail.

Could anyone offer any assistance please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the line height using the `rotatingPointOffset` property.

```
var canvas = window._canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

var rect = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 100,
    top: 100,
    width: 100,
    height: 75,
    fill: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.5)',
    rotatingPointOffset: 60
});
canvas.add(rect);
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6ydPq/71/)

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't find this anywhere